# Error and warning :Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I am working in a project and apparently it throws exception Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

here is my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.ayon.visiterbook"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

compile 'com.sdsmdg.tastytoast:tastytoast:0.1.1'}
```

and my gradle file:

```
buildscript
```

{

```
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}}allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}}task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

Comment: set `implementation` instead of  `compile`

Answer (score 1):

It's a warning that google has changed `compile` to `implementation` and `api`, `compile` will removed at end of 2018

so Just change your `compile` into `implementation` like

to

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.sdsmdg.tastytoast:tastytoast:0.1.1'
```

this

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.sdsmdg.tastytoast:tastytoast:0.1.1'
```

Comment: if you want to expose some module use API

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `compile` to `implementation` in `build.gradle` file works for me.